# Chi-Sqare test and Continuous values

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-selection, mathematics, chi-square-test

How does chi-square test work for continuous variables. I see that it is used in most papers to test dependencies between continuous explanatory variables and the target variable. Please how does this work mathematically? Are there any papers where i can refer this?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Can you please give an example of these papers? To my knowledge chi-square is based counting discrete events, on the contrary.

Comment: Here is an example file:///C:/Users/USER/OneDrive/Desktop/project%20combination/Naive%20Bayes/TF-IDF%20CHIQUARE.pdf

Comment: You gave a link to your local hard drive, I cant see it.

Comment: Sorry.. here  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/362393885_Efficient_Machine_Learning_Approaches_to_Detect_Fake_News_of_Covid-19

Comment: Ok I looked at the paper and it's not clear at all, they don't explain well. As far I know they must be counting something to do a chi square, it cannot use the TFIDF values. This paper is not very good quality and it's not published in a good quality NLP conference. There might even be errors, the results don't seem consistent with the state of the art. You can try to ask the authors directly.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Appreciate